# SQL Select Posts Where Keywords Matches the Users Interests

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blogs

I'm currently experiencing some technical difficulties with my blog web app. I wanna make a Discover page where users can find new posts based on there interests. I will accomplish this by adding keywords to these posts. That way I can just select the posts where the interests from the user and the post keywords matches. I've now realized that I have wandered into deep waters.

After a lot of researching, I've now decided to share my problem and maybe get some guidance. I have 4 tables, **"users"**, **"posts"**, **"keywords"**, **"interests"**. The **"keywords"** table contains **"post_id"** and **"keyword_value"**. The "interests" table contains **"user_id"** and **"interest_value"**.

Now, how can I select the posts from **"posts"** table where the keywords connected to the post matches the interests that are connected to current user.

Thanks in advance. All response are appreciated.

DATA SAMPLES:

**"users"**
[[image: 1]]

**"posts"**
[image]

**"interests"**
[image]

**"keywords"**
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, along with any attempt you have made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been very helpful if you had provided some data as well. I suspect that you have described your tables wrong - I think you meant that the **keywords** table has **post_id** and **keyword_value** and the **interests** table has **user_id** and **interest_value**. If that's the case, then this query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE post_id IN (
        SELECT post_id
        FROM keywords
        WHERE keyword_value IN (
                SELECT interest_value
                FROM interests
                WHERE user_id = @userId
                )
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your solution do not return any posts wether you have have a interest that matches a keyword or not.

Comment: Are you sure submitting the `@userId` parameter correctly? Did you try replacing `@userId` in my code with `1`, for example?

Comment: Yes, I've checked.

Comment: I added an image to my original answer to show the test schema that I tried the query against, as well as the results it produced.